# insert the contents of a file to another (in a specific line of the file that is sent)-BASH/LINUX

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried doing it with `cat` and then after I type the second file I added `| head -$line | tail -1` but it doesn't work because it performs `cat` first.

Any ideas? I need to do it with `cat` or something else.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd probably use `sed` for this job:

```
line=3
sed -e "${line}r file2" file1
```

If you're looking to overwrite `file1` and you have GNU `sed`, add the `-i` option.  Otherwise, write to a temporary file and then copy/move the temporary file over the original, cleaning up as necessary (that's the `trap` stuff below).  Note: copying the temporary over the file preserves links; moving does not (but is swifter, especially if the file is big).

```
line=3
tmp="./sed.$$"
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
sed -e "${line}r file2" file1 > $tmp
cp $tmp file1
rm -f $tmp
trap 0
```

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun, and just because we all love `ed`, the standard editor, here's an `ed` version. It's very efficient (`ed` is a *genuine* text editor)!

```
ed -s file2 <<< $'3r file1\nw'
```

If the line number is stored in the variable `line` then:

```
ed -s file2 <<< "${line}r file1"$'\nw'
```

Just to please Zack, here's one version with less bashism, in case you don't like bash (personally, I don't like pipes and subshells, I prefer herestrings, but hey, as I said, that's only to please Zack):

```
printf "%s\n" "${line}r file1" w | ed -s file2
```

or (to please Sorpigal):

```
printf "%dr %s\nw" "$line" file1 | ed -s file2
```

As Jonathan Leffler mentions in a comment, and if you intend to use this method in a script, use a heredoc (it's usually the most efficient):

```
ed -s file2 <<EOF
${line}r file1
w
EOF
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. Don't hesitate to leave a comment if you feel you need to express yourself about the ways to drive `ed`, the standard editor.

Comment: This is clever, but if I upvote anything that uses `ed` and bashisms in the same breath, I lose my old-beard status.  `printf '3r file1\nw' | ed -s file2`, please.

Comment: A straight old-fashioned here document (`<<EOF`) will work instead of the `<<<` Bashism.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what I usually use in scripts, but it's messy on one-liners. Post edited to your please :)

Comment: It's worse than messy; it's a non-starter in a one-liner, requiring a minimum of two lines (for an empty here document, which could be better handled by redirecting from `/dev/null`, of course).  I'm not clear there was a requirement for the script to be a one-liner (though there's no harm in making it one when it's feasible without undue contortions).  Here documents work fine typing a script at the terminal — not in a script.

Comment: That `printf` would probably be better as `printf '%dr %s\nw' "$line" file1`

Comment: _"P.S. Don't hesitate to leave a comment if you feel you need to express yourself about the ways to drive `ed`, the standard editor."_  

- _An `ed` enthusiast_

Comment: Doesn't work for me, `file1.txt: No such file or directory`, actually made a typo confusing , with .

Answer (score 4):

```
cat file1 >>file2
```

will append content of file1 to file2.

```
cat file1 file2
```

will concatenate file1 and file2 and send output to terminal.

```
cat file1 file2 >file3
```

will create or overwite file3 with concatenation of file1 and file2

```
cat file1 file2 >>file3
```

will append concatenation of file1 and file2 to end of file3.

**Edit**:

For trunking file2 before adding file1:

```
sed -e '11,$d' -i file2 && cat file1 >>file2
```

or for making a 500 lines file:

```
n=$((500-$(wc -l <file1)))
sed -e "1,${n}d" -i file2 && cat file1 >>file2
```

Comment: I know that (don't want to sound rude) what i want to do is cat file1 >>file2 but "cat" it to a certain line of file2.

Do you have any idea of how to do it? You'll make my day!

Comment: Of course, file1 as to be less than 500 lines in my last sample!

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do it, but I like to to choose a way that involves making tools.

First, setup test environment

```
rm -rf /tmp/test
mkdir /tmp/test
printf '%s\n' {0..9} > /tmp/test/f1
printf '%s\n' {one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten} > /tmp/test/f2
```

Now let's make the tool, and in this first pass we'll implement it badly.

```
# insert contents of file $1 into file $2 at line $3
insert_at () { insert="$1" ; into="$2" ; at="$3" ; { head -n $at "$into" ; ((at++)) ; cat "$insert" ; tail -n +$at "$into" ; } ; }
```

Then run the tool to see the amazing results.

```
$ insert_at /tmp/test/f1 /tmp/test/f2 5
```

But wait, the result is on stdout! What about overwriting the original? No problem, we can make another tool for that.

```
insert_at_replace () { tmp=$(mktemp) ; insert_at "$@" > "$tmp" ; mv "$tmp" "$2" ; }
```

And run it

```
$ insert_at_replace /tmp/test/f1 /tmp/test/f2 5
$ cat /tmp/test/f2
```

"Your implementation sucks!"

I know, but that's the beauty of making simple tools. Let's replace `insert_at` with the sed version.

```
insert_at () { insert="$1" ; into="$2" ; at="$3" ; sed -e "${at}r ${insert}" "$into" ; }
```

And `insert_at_replace` keeps working (of course). The implementation of `insert_at_replace` can also be changed to be less buggy, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: funny how theres literally no resource online that explains how to do this well, I wish you wouldve shared your more final version of this. This could be useful to people looking to solve a problem and not doing homework.

Comment: @qodeninja: the answer by gniourf_gniourf (using ed) is how you do it well.

Answer (score 2):

I like doing this with `head` and `tail` if you don't mind managing a new file:

```
head -n 16 file1 >  file3 &&
cat        file2 >> file3 &&
tail -n+56 file1 >> file3
```

> You can collapse this onto one line if you like. Then, if you really need it to overwrite file1, do: `mv file3 file1` (optionally include `&&` between commands).

Notes:

- `head -n 16 file1` means first 16 lines of file1
- `tail -n+56 file1` means file1 starting from line 56 to the end
- Hence, I actually skipped lines 17 through 55 from file1.
- Of course, if you could change 56 to 17 so no lines are skipped.
- I prefer to mix simple `head` and `tail` commands then try a magic `sed` command.