# Issue with bash script running awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to extract the contents of two files and merge them to a third file in my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter file1: " file1
read -p "Enter file2: " file2

merge=file3

awk -v var1="$file1" -v var2="$file2" 'NR==4{system("cat" var1)} 1' var2 > $merge
chmod 777 $merge
```

I got the above command from the following:

[awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036707/insert-text-from-a-file-to-specific-line-numbers-on-another-text-file)

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
awk:fatal:cannot open file 'var2' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

If I were to run the above command on the command line on my linux box as follows:

```
awk 'NR==4{system("cat file1.txt")} 1' file2.txt > file3.txt
```

where file1, file2 and file3 are replaced by their corresponding names on the disk, the command works as expected.

Since I would be using this command very regularly, I thought of converting it into a script.

Any thoughts on what I am missing out because of which the awk command fails from within the script?

TIA

Comment: Please define merging files with illustrative input files (2-3 lines each) and the required output from the merge. If you just looking to put 2 files "together" does `cat file1 file2 > file3` solve your problem? Else edit your Q to show your requirements. Good luck.

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Comment: Possible duplicate [insert the contents of a file to another (in a specific line of the file that is sent)-BASH/LINUX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14044032/3422102)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 awk -v var1="$file1" 'NR==4{system("cat " var1)} 1' "$file2" > $merge

 chmod 777 $merge
```

that said, your approach overwrites `"$merge"` every time, and lacks proper shell quotation for `"$file1" / var1` at the `system()` call, and also `"cat"` needs to be become `"cat "` otherwise you're prepending `"cat"` to your filename, but without a corresponding shell command.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
awk -v var1="$file1" -v var2="$file2" 'NR==4{system("cat" var1)} 1' var2 > $merge
```

command does look for file named `var2` which is not found and this lead to error. If you wish to process file based on GNU `AWK` variable you might harness [ARGC and ARGV](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html) following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{fname="file.txt";ARGV[ARGC]=fname;ARGC+=1}{print}'
```

above code would output content of `file.txt` even despite it did not got it as argument at command line. For simplicity sake I set `fname` variable to just text, but there is nothing preventing you from calculating it.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*